# python: my function change the argument for no reason

Tags: python, arrays, function, global

I have this function:

```
def change_position(old_particles):
    inc_r=0.5
    inc_angle=0.5
    N=len(old_particles)
    particlesx=old_particles
    a=random.randint(0,N-1)
    b=random.randint(0,1)
    max_angle=np.pi*2
    c=random.randint(0,1)
    print 'old_particles before change', old_particles
    print 'new before change', particlesx
    if b==1:
        if c==1:
            particlesx[a][b]=particlesx[a][b]+inc_angle
            if particlesx[a][b]>max_angle:
                particlesx[a][b]=particlesx[a][b]-max_angle
            print 'cambiamos particula',a, particlesx[a][b]
    if b==1:
        if c==0:
            particlesx[a][b]=particlesx[a][b]-inc_angle
            if particlesx[a][b]<0:
                particlesx[a][b]=particlesx[a][b]+max_angle
            print 'cambiamos',a, particlesx[a][b]
    if b==0:
        if c==0:
            particlesx[a][b]=particlesx[a][b]+inc_r
            if particlesx[a][b]>1:
                particlesx[a][b]=particlesx[a][b]-inc_r
            print 'cambiamos',a, particlesx[a][b]
    if b==0:
        if c==1:
            particlesx[a][b]=particlesx[a][b]-inc_r
            if particlesx[a][b]<0:
                particlesx[a][b]=particlesx[a][b]+inc_r
            print 'cambiamos',a, particlesx[a][b]
    print'after change', particlesx
    print'old_particles after change', old_particles
    return particlesx, a
```

the problem is that for a reason I dont understand, the function change not only the value of 'particlesx' but also the value of old_particles so the values of both arrays at the end of the script are the same not only in the function but also outside of the function. Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following:

```
particlesx=old_particles
```

does not make a copy of the list. Instead, it makes both `particlesx` and `old_particles` refer to the same list. When you change one, they both change.

To make the two independent of one another, you need to make a copy:

```
import copy
...
particlesx = copy.deepcopy(old_particles)
```

Comment: for instance: if you the elements in the class are immutable, you can as well use the syntax new_p = old_p[:]

Comment: @Ant: Which here, they aren't (the elements appear to be lists themselves). Hence my recommendation to use `deepcopy()`.